# install Magento 2 to sub-url nginx

Tags: magento2, nginx

Does anybody try to use built-in [nginx.conf.sample](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample) file
in case of installing magento to sub uri, like as:

'http://example.com/**shop**'

What changes is needed for correctly using Magento2 code in subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

change core url in table "core_config_data" to new url only. No special